# JavaScript/d3.js Граф. Как получить массив всех вершин связанных с указанной?

Tags: javascript, массивы, arraylist, d3.js, graph

объект Граф (graph) в d3.js состоит из массива вершин (nodes) и массива ребер (edges).

массив вершин (nodes) имеет структуру:

```
[{ 'index':0 }.., ]
```

массив ребер (edges) имеет структуру:

```
[{ 'source':{'index':0},  
   'target':{'index':1}}, 
 { 'source':{...},  
   'target':{...}}
                ...]
```

Такой вопрос: Как указав вершину получить массив всех связанных с ней вершин 
следующего вида:

например:
задал нулевую вершину на выходе вернуло массив 1,2,3 ..т.е. с нулевой связаны первая, вторая и третья..

```
{0:[1,2,3]}
```

Как сделать такое преобразование?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй перебрать массив и взять все 'target' для выбранного 'source':

```
var Node = 1;
var res = [];

for(var index in edges) {
    if (edges[index].source == Node) res.push(edges[index].target);
}

var ret = {};
ret[Node] = res;
```

Если нужны все вершины со всеми ребрами, тогда так:

```
var res = {};

for(var node in nodes) {
    var rel = [];

    for(var edge in edges) {
        if (edges[edge].source == nodes[node].index) rel.push(edges[edge].target);
    }

    res[nodes[node].index] = rel;
}
```

Еще вариант для получения массивов связанных вершин для всех вершин графа (с одним обходом массива):

```
var res = {};

for(var edge in edges) {
    if (!res.hasOwnProperty(res[edges[edge].source].toString())) {
        res[edges[edge].source] = [];
    }

    res[edges[edge].source].push(edges[edge].target);
}
```